# jQuery selector not fetching all rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've have some little problem with jquery selectors. When I write the HTML like this:

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    echo "<div>";
    for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++)
    {
        if($j==2)
            echo "<div id='n$i$j' class='news-container has-border'>$i$j</div>";
        else
            echo "<div id='n$i$j' class='news-container'>$i$j</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

I can later access all divs with jquery except the ones in third row like so:

```
$("#n11").css("background-color","red"); <-- WORKS
$("#n21").css("background-color","red"); <-- WORKS
$("#n31").css("background-color","red"); <-- NOT WORKING
```

this javascript code also works

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
    for(j=1; j<=3; j++)
        console.log($("#n"+i+j).attr("id"));
```

it writes me all 9 id's into console. but this code changes only first 6 divs.

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
    for(j=1; j<=3; j++)
        $("#n"+i+j).html("news");
```

I've tried to concat in all ways possible but always get the same result..

OK after applying anyslider() plugin.. i've changed the id's to classes and it worked.. so i guess the problem is not fixed only tricked!

Comment: Post your html, not your php.

Comment: `$("n31")` --> `$("#n31")`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That's true, but if he says 2 of them work, I assume he just made a typo in his question.

Comment: Yap.. only a typo for this post.. my code is a bit different but the root of the problem is the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if($j==2) {
        echo "<div id='n".$i.$j."' class='news-container has-border'>".$i.$j."</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div id='n".$i.$j."' class='news-container'>".$i.$j."</div>";
    }
```

I think you missed #

```
 $("#n11").css("background-color","red"); 
 $("#n21").css("background-color","red"); 
 $("#n31").css("background-color","red");
```

working for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#n11").css("background-color","red"); 
 $("#n12").css("background-color","red"); 
 $("#n13").css("background-color","red"); 
});
</script>
```

In php

```
<?php
    for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div>";
        for($j=1; $j<=3; $j++)
        {
            if($j==2) {
                echo "<div id='n".$i.$j."' class='news-container has-border'>".$i.$j."</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<div id='n".$i.$j."' class='news-container'>".$i.$j."</div>";
            }
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: naa i forgot to put it in this post, only to change it for easier understanding of the problem! it's with # in my code!.... I've edited the post now